# Is Affected Rows of Insert statement always 1?

Tags: sql-server, database

By affected rows, I mean the statement runs successfully, ie. no syntax error or duplicate primary key, etc.

Is it meaningless to check the return value of ExecuteNonQuery()?

```
SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO.. ", connection);
if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()!=1)
  throw new Exception();
```

Comment: Absolutely not. What if your insert statement used a select as the source so it would insert more than 1 row? There are other ways you can get an insert to insert more than 1 row too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

So no, the number can be different than 1, especially if multiple rows are being inserted with the statement.

Comment: Trigger is a valid point. Even if I insert a single row, some triggers may run.

Answer (score 0):

No.

```
create table #foo (
  id int primary key,
  name text
);

insert into #foo values
(1,'a'),
(2,'b');
```

(2 row(s) affected)

Answer (score 0):

In Insert statement number of affected rows depend upon the values insert into the table.
If you enter value for two rows, then two rows will be affected.